Postgres - Improving multi-column GIN text search performance
I've got a schema for customer records a bit like:
account_id - UUID
name - text

I currently have a GIN index that looks like:
... USING GIN (account_id, name gin_trgm_ops)

We have a mix of accounts. Some have a lot of customers (10m+) and some only have a few (10k+). We have a lot of queries that look like:
SELECT from customers WHERE account_id=<account_id> AND 
(
  name LIKE 'Bob%'
  OR name LIKE 'Alice%'
  OR name LIKE 'Dave%'
  OR name LIKE 'Carol%'
  OR name LIKE 'Edward%'
  OR name LIKE 'Fay%'
)

For large customers the index performance is good (queries ~2s). For small customers the index performance is comparatively poor (also ~2s). This matters due to how often we run these queries.
Is there a way to improve this for smaller customers? We've noticed that replacing the index with a simple btree index on account_id is faster - scanning all the records for a single small account is faster than doing the index bitmap work across all accounts. Obviously, this is a lot slower on the large accounts.
I think partitioning the table is the only way forward here. However, I'm hoping someone has a bright idea :)

replacing the index with a simple btree index on account_id is faster: why replace? Two indexes seem to make sense here: a btree index on account_id and the gin index on name alone.

What happens if one of the search terms is for 'Cy%'?

Your index doesn't look very sensible to me.  A multicolumn GIN index is pretty much identical to multiple single-column GIN indexes.  It isn't like a Btree index, where selectivity on multiple columns can be multiplied by being in the same index.
Since all your LIKE queries are fixed prefix, you could get a benefit from a multicolumn btree index.
create index on customers (account_id , name text_pattern_ops);

If they aren't really all fixed prefix, you might want to try the multicolumn GiST index.  I'm not a fan of gist_trgm_ops, but this might be one case where it would work well.
As you noted, partitioning could also work well.  But if you have a large number of accounts this could become hard to manage it.

This looks like it might work. Downside that %search% won't work, but I think we can live without that. Thank you!
Ultimately, what I really want is a btree of gin indexes. e.g. a btree on account_id and then each leaf is a pointer to a gin index on name :)
